# AWS Lex V2 - DailogHook Validation

Tags: amazon-lex

Does anyone know how I check what slot I am processing if I do some validation at the slot level? As I have looked at the event payload and there seems to be no reference to the slot you are calling your Lambda function on.

Answer (score 0):

At present the Lex event passed to Lambda functions does not contain any hint as to which slot is presently being ellicted.

However, looking at the `slots` array in the event, you can determine when to validate based on the current value.

Values that have not yet been elicited are `null`; whereas values that have been ascertained from the user have a non-null value.

You can validate the non-nulls and assuming you handle the scenarios correctly you should be fine. By that I mean if the value fails validation you will need to issue an `ElicitSlot` prompt for the same slot; potentially with a useful error message. If the value passes validation you can issue a `Delegate` response and allow Lex to continue processing accordingly.

Below is a sample event received by my Lambda function for a V2 Lex bot:

```
    "intent": {
        "slots": {
            "duration": null,
            "reason": null,
            "quantity": {
                "shape": "Scalar",
                "value": {
                    "originalValue": "2",
                    "resolvedValues": [
                        "2"
                    ],
                    "interpretedValue": "2"
                }
            }
        },
        "confirmationState": "None",
        "name": "MainIntent",
        "state": "InProgress"
    },
```

In my example, `MainIntent` has three slots but only one has a value. My Lambda function will validate the non-nulls and then delegate to Lex for the rest of the processing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Lex v2 set the invocationLabel to something unique for that DialogCodeHook. For a slot validation code hook this is the attribute:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lexv2/latest/APIReference/API_DialogCodeHookInvocationSetting.html#lexv2-Type-DialogCodeHookInvocationSetting-invocationLabel

In the event passed to your lambda you'll find the invocationLabel at the top level and you can use it to control what code paths you run:

```
{
    "invocationSource": "DialogCodeHook",
    "invocationLabel": "MyIntent_MySlot_ValidationCodeHook",
...
}
```

I would highly recommend always setting invocationLabels on all your DialogCode hooks.